# Freecom portable drive is not working with longer cable

Tags: external-hard-drive, usb-storage, portable-harddrive

I got a [FREECOM 2.5" Mobile Drive XXS 500 gb](http://www.freecom.com/Products/External-Hard-Drives/Mobile-Hard-Drives/Mobile-Drive-XXS) portable hdd, but on my laptop which stands on a laptop cooler it's coming unhandy for me to plug-it in, because the cooler it's too tall, so my hdd has to lean all the time.
The usb cable that came with the hdd it's like 2.5 cm without the connector heads, and total of ~8 cm length.

First I bought a 1.5 m cable, I plugged it on the hdd, then it power up and lost power afterwards.

Now I tried a shorter cable which is: 32 cm and total of 42 cm with the connector heads. which resulted the same, not powering the hdd correctly.

Does anybody has experience with this particular hdd drive model and successfully replaced the original cable with a longer one ?

Comment: From where did you buy the cables? are they reliable?
Try using the HDD with longer cables on different computer and see if the result is the same

Comment: Do you know if the cable as such is not defect?

Comment: I solved it, I'm waiting for 3-4 hours to be able to anwer my own question. I found an old usb extender, it worked out perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I found an old usb extender cable from old usb dongle which 52 cm in length without the connector heads